# Mixing Oil Types

Tags: honda, accord, oil-change

I have a 2009 Accord with about 122k miles. I have always used conventional oil but recently I had the car to the dealer for a recall that involved replacing engine parts and oil change. However they used synthetic. Do I need to always use synthetic oil for all future changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can go back to regular oil next oil change. Its only bad to go back to non-synthetic if the car has been on a steady diet of Synthetic for a long time or is designed to use synthetic oil.

Comment: You are really getting into opinion here ... I realize your opinion is based on many years of wrenching, but I also realize oil questions can contribute a lot of opinion due to other reasons. You say it's bad to go from a synthetic back to dino oil after it's been on there for a long time. I would disagree with this, but would also say it is an opinion on my part. How is a vehicle *designed* to use synthetic oil? To my knowledge they aren't: manufacturers make the recommendation to use synth, but 5w-30 is still 5w-30 and will behave as such. Both will provide protection if used correctly.

Comment: In my opinion, everything is an opinion.

Comment: An engine designed for synthetic oil shouldn't be used with conventional oil.  This is because the conventional oil does not behave the same as conventional oil at certain temperatures.

Answer (score 2):

The spec for a 2009 Honda Accord is plain old oil; no specific need for synthetic. As long as you get your oil changed regularly, it won't be breaking down to the point where the difference is measurable (except in your wallet). You won't have any problems switching between synthetic and non-synthetic.

Comment: Exactly! I change my oil every 3k unlike their recommendation of 5k. I will probably just go back.